# Why can't I mark a question as a duplicate of a question with no answers, submitted less than 24 hours ago?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, specific-question

This question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425555/need-info-about-neterr-cache-miss, appears to be a duplicate of this question, [Bizarre Error in Chrome Developer Console - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408931/bizarre-error-in-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-cache-miss), asked just 21 hours beforehand.

I get that you shouldn't be able to mark questions as duplicates of questions which were asked months ago which also have no answers, but surely you should be able to do this on questions which aren't even a day old?

Comment: I'm curious as to why question age should even matter.  By asking the question again, you're fragmenting the effort to answer it, whether it's one day or one year old.

Comment: @fbueckert - hmmm if both questions are asked at exactly the same time, which one is a duplicate and who gets the credit if it's a good question :-o ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166724/165773

Comment: @fbueckert: well, if the question was asked months ago, there's probably no effort to answer it anymore that you need to worry about fragmenting.

Comment: There's an asinine rule in effect that a question must have an upvoted answer to be a target of a dup vote.  It does make cleaning up repeat questions from the same user very difficult, or a question storm when a Chrome update has a bug, you can only flag a moderator.

Comment: @HansPassant: You can always dup-target questions from the same user, irrespective of answers.

Comment: Okay, I'll buy that.  Last time I actually tried it, it was on the same question asked with a different user account.  A simple workaround for users to repeatedly ask the same question :(

Comment: @misterManSam The one with better title, description, code, mvce etc (*if required*) should be used to mark the other as duplicate... It's very unlikely that two users post the exact same thing at the same time...

Comment: Related reading: [Duo of buddies can circumvent duplicate closures under the new rule requiring an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171371)

Comment: Flags work well. Moderators are not limited by the must-have-an-answer rule.